# do not want append in href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change entire URL by changing the dropdown.

```
$('#year').on('change', function(){
    var year = $(this).val();
    window.location.href = window.location.href+"?year="+year;
});
```

I think, above code should change entire `URL` every time.
But, when I do it more than once, then it starts appending the `year` in current URL.

I need something like this:

```
example.com?year=2014
example.com?year=2015
```

Right now, I am getting:

```
 example.com?year=2014?year=2015
```

Comment: try just.... `=window.location+"?year"+year;`

Comment: @gloomy.penguin : I got it actually. I need just path not without parameters.

Comment: You're concatenating your window.location every time the drop-down changes.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code to this:

```
$('#year').on('change', function(){
    var year = $(this).val();
    window.location.href = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname+"?year="+year;

    OR

    window.location.href = location.pathname+"?year="+year;
});
```

Comment: You don't need to build an absolute URL. `location.href = location.pathname + "?year=" + year` should work too.

Comment: Yikes, that's an ugly solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the current address and replace using a regular expression:

```
$('#year').on('change', function(){
    var year = $(this).val();
    old_href = window.location.href;
    new_href = old_href.replace(/(year=)[^\&]+/, '$1' + year);
    window.location.href = new_href;
});
```